# Speed up repetitive KMeans in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I currently have a dataframe of a billion rows on the commute times of 1 million people. There are two columns, one is the unique ID of each person and the other is time.

I want to perform KMeans clustering on each person based on their commute times. Selecting the commute times of a single person and doing Kmeans is very fast, but to do it a million times would take very long.

What I am doing right now:

```
for i in distinct_commuter_id:
    df_input = df.filter(df['id']==i)
    ... # run KMeans on df_input
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.